# why i cant cout the array in the second loop when i use sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) as a condition for the for loop?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

why i cant cout the array in the second loop when i use sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) as a condition for the for loop ?

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main(){
        int num;
        int array[] = {};
        cout << " enter the numbers " << endl;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++ )
            cin >> array [i];
        num = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); 
            for ( int x = 0 ; x < num  ; x ++)
            cout << array[x] << endl;
```

Comment: Could you please explain in a little more detail what is the expected and actual outcome?

Answer (score 1):

Your array has size 0.

```cpp
int array[] = {};
```

This initializes the array with a size of 0. It's the same as doing

```cpp
int array[0];
```

Arrays like these cannot grow or shrink, so they cannot change their size. What you likely want to do is

```cpp
int array[5];
```

which gives it a size of `5`.
Further your `sizeof` code will then work as well. I assumed you want a size of 5 since your first loop goes to 5.

Note that these really cannot ever change size. You make it size 0, it stays size 0, no matter what you do after. In my suggested fix, its size 5, and it will stay size 5, you can't resize it.

By the way, writing to locations 0-5 on an array with size 0 like you do is not okay, since the array does not have any such index. It's undefined behavior to access positions out of bounds of this array.

Comment: yes, I can just write 5 but I actually want to let the program know the size of my array without writing 5 is that possible?

Comment: If you want to "dynamically" decide the size of the array it gets quite complicated and is out of the scope of a SO answer. You need to look into `new`, `new[]`, `delete` and `delete[]`. This: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/ is a good guide, and you can look up other tutorials as well, the keyword is "dynamic memory".

Comment: @MohammedAlhajj If you want a dynamic array your first choice should be a standard library container like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Manual memory management with `new[]` and `delete[]` can be complicated and lead to bugs and memory leaks.

Comment: @Blastfurnace although that is true for sure, learning new[] and delete[] is a necessary stepping stone towards understanding std::vector